# Scope is working a bit strange inside an express route

Tags: node.js, express, router

I got the following issue: the `options` variable in the express router is not using the correct `options` variable. Any suggestions?

```
router.use('/test1', new Factory("test1") );
router.use('/test2', new Factory("test2") );

function Factory(options) {
    router.use((req,res,next) => {
        res.json(options)
    })
    return router
};

/*
Returns :
/test1 "test1"
/test2 "test1" ???
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Factory(options) {

    return (req,res,next) => {
        res.json(options)
    })
};

router.use('/test1', new Factory("test1") );
router.use('/test2', new Factory("test2") );
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr;

Use this instead.

```
router.get("/:options", Factory);

function Factory(req, res, next){
    const options = req.params.options;
    res.json(options);
}
```

### Why what you have does not work as expected

In your Factory you do this:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.json(options);
});
```

This statement tells express: hey whenever a request comes in then run this middleware:

```
(req, res, next) => {
        res.json(options);
    })
```

Note that you do not specify a route for this, it's just in the format `app.use(handler)`, so it will run for every request.

above that you do this:

`router.get("/test1", new Factory("test30"));`

Now when express sees this it says, oh here's a handler for  `/test1`, let me register that handler to that route. When it registers the handler it comes across this expression: `new Factory("test1")`. Note that this is an expression and will get executed **when the route is registered** and NOT when handling a request. It can essentially be rewritten like this: `router.get("/test1", Factory("test30"))`, which results in:

```
router.get("/test1", router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.json("test1");
    return router;
}));
```

This part:

```
router.get("/test1", )
```

depends on this part:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.json("test1");
        return router;
    })
```

Which means that the latter will be executed first. This means that at the end of it all your code actually looks something like this:

```
const resultOfThisLine = 
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.json("test1"); //You passed test1 as options to the factory
    return router;
});

router.get("/test1", resultOfThisLine);

router.get("/test2", router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.json("test1"); //You passed test1 as options to he factory
    return router;
}));
```

As you can see,

```
   router.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.json("test1"); //You passed test1 as options to the factory
        return router;
    });
```

is actually registered before everything else and since it returns a response, nothing else will ever get called. Moreover, this handler will respond to ANY request because there is no specific url attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reactions. It made me realize I need to create a new router object.

Like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/test1', new Factory("test1"));
router.use('/test2', new Factory("test2"));

function Factory(options) {
    const router2 = express.Router();

    router2.get("", handleRoute.bind({ options: options }))
    router2.post("", handleRoute.bind({ options: options }))

    function handleRoute(req, res, next) {
        res.json({ message: "hello", options: options })
    }

    return router2
};
```